# Problems with Spring Integration HTTP outbound channel adapter

Tags: http, adapter, channel, outbound

I am using spring integration 2.2.4 and am trying to add HTTP outbound channel adapter for invoking GET/POST REST services. Currently the adapter is getting displayed in the graph view but when I am trying to drag and use it in the code , it is not getting created.

I have added the HTTP namespaces URI as required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">


<http:outbound-channel-adapter channel=""/>
```

If I am trying to add this manually in the source XML then I am getting error as "The matching wildcard is strict , but no declaration could be found for element http:outbound-channel-adapter"

Can anyone help me out here with a sample http-outbound channel adapter? Am I missing something here.

Comment: Did you check the example here? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/http/pom.xml. Verify if you have added the right dependencies. If you have added do the dependencies as mentioned, do force an update of maven repositories.